# What do these old floppy disk standards mean: DMF and DSED/HD?

Tags: floppy

I see on floppy some "standards" called SSSD, or DSSD.
Some of them are known for me some other not.

| Standard | Definition |
| --- | --- |
| DMF | #? |
| DSDD | #Double Sided Double Density |
| DSED | #Double Sided ? |
| DSHD | #Double Side High density? |
| DSSD | #Double Sided Single Density |
| SSSD | #Single Sided Single Density |

What does it mean DMF? And DSED/HD?

Comment: Old 5.25" floppy disks had full double sided capacity of 360KB  . Newer 3.5 inch disks had 720KB and 1440KB double density.  Today (95%+) you can only use 3.5 inch floppies with a USB drive.  Works up to Windows 11 Pro today

Comment: IIRC - and I'm not sure I do - DSHD (yes, "high density") was a special IBM format that squeezed ~1.8MB onto a 3.5" floppy. It was never widely supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DMF](https://www.winimage.com/wimushlp/wini1a1y.htm) is a Distribution Media Format Floppy Disk, it's 3½-inch having 1680 KB compared to other disks having 1440 KB. Needed a special device to copy them hence making them somewhat protected.

DSED — Double-Sided Extended-Density

Densities vary from single (SD), double (DD), high density (HD), than extended (ED) and finally Triple density (TD).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_floppy_disk_formats

Answer (score 3):

Distribution Media Format (DMF) is a format for floppy disks that Microsoft used to distribute software. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_Media_Format).

In 1988, Y-E Data introduced a drive for 2.88 MB Double-Sided Extended-Density (DSED) diskettes which was used by IBM in its top-of-the-line PS/2 and some RS/6000 models and in the second-generation NeXTcube and NeXTstation. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floppy_disk).

The term DS/HD means double sided high density.Sometimes called MF2-HD. [Source](https://www.floppydisk.com/dsdd-dshd).